# Python gtts language detection

Tags: python, text-to-speech

Hello guys I am working on a multi language social network and I want to add an option to listen to the post as audio I tried gtts with python and I was just asking if there is a way to detect the language automatically.
I was about to use a module called googletrans in python to detect the language of the post and then read it without translating but I feel it's not the best solution.
I'll be thankful if you passed any piece of help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `textblob` to detect the language: `pip install textblob`

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("bonjour")
text = b.detect_language()
```

and then use `pyttsx3` to read it out loud:
`pip install pyttsx3`

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init() # object creation


rate = engine.getProperty('rate')   # getting details of current speaking rate
print (rate)                        #printing current voice rate
engine.setProperty('rate', 125)     # setting up new voice rate



voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       #getting details of current voice
#engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  #changing index, changes voices. o for male
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)   #changing index, changes voices. 1 for female

engine.say(text)

engine.save_to_file('Hello World', 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```